# Change the code to not construct the path from user controlled data

Tags: java, sonarqube, refactoring

SonarQube linter is showing this error `Change this code to not construct the path from user-controller data` for the following code:

```
public static File zipping(List<File> files, String fileName){
    try (var fos= new FileOutputStream(fileName))
    {
    }  
}
@GetMapping(value="",produces="application/zip")
public ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource> gen(@RequestParam String version, @RequestParam String type) {
List<Files> files = service.getFiles(version,type);
String fileName=type+version+".zip";
var zipFile=zipping(files,fileName);

}
```

**My thoughts:** I understand that the zipFileName passed to the function may be invalid or not exist, but I am not sure how to avoid this error.

Comment: You haven't provided enough context to answer your question. What sort of program is this? Where does `zipFileName` come from?

Comment: And the concern is not that `zipFileName` might not exist, but that this might allow a user to overwrite one of the application's jar files, perhaps with their own data.

Comment: @tgdavies I have added more code. Do let me know if you think something else is needed. The function `zipping` is inside a Utility class which gets called from the controller.

Comment: @tgdavies In the current case I am putting the extension of the file as `.zip` So it will get saved on the file system as a .zip file. Is there a possibility for some malicious input to overwrite one of the application's jar file? Also since jar files will be under .m2 repository to achieve that the user should provide the path to the .m2 folder maliciously. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

In your case the problem is that the `fileName`, passed to `zipping` function is constructed inside the controller method from client-provided parameters. This is considered an I/O path injection security vulnerability. [There is a dedicated SonarQube rule that is responsible for that](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2083/).

To solve this problem, I recommend you to go to **'How can I fix it'** section and follow the suggestions of the SonarQube team. For each rule, they have an example of how it could be fixed. Hope it helped.